# How to combine these two commands

Tags: powershell

I'm just looking to make one command our of these two

```
Get-ChildItem "\\myfileserver\out\*" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(?<=^.{3}).{13}', '.' }
get-childitem "\\myfileserver\out\*" | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(".vfmpclmadj.", ".sa.") }
```

Comment: This is a different one. I got most of it but running two commands seems like a waste.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the two operations like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\myfileserver\out\*" | Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.Name -replace '(?<=^.{3}).{13}', '.').Replace(".vfmpclmadj.", ".sa.") }
```

Comment: Could you explain this part for me "'(?<=^"?. I understand whats its doing but I dont understand the why.

Comment: @user770022 `(?<=expression)` is a [_positive look-behind assertion_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zero-width-positive-lookbehind-assertions), it ensures the replacement only occurs at position 4 (the only position immediately preceded by a match for `^.{3}`) in the input string

Answer (score 1):

You could chain -replace.  I would make sure the get-childitem finishes before modifying the thing you're looping on.  Backslashing the periods that are regex.

```
(Get-ChildItem \\myfileserver\out\*) | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(?<=^.{3}).{13}', 
  '.' -replace '\.vfmpclmadj\.', '.sa.' } -whatif
```